# Recreate a file with VS2012 & TFS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I cannot re-create the file if it is controlled by TFS.

Steps to reproduce:

> - Create a new console app.
> - Add a new file: Class1.cs
> - Check-in entire solution to TFS.
> - Remove Class1.cs.
> - Create a Class1.cs again.

I get a message box with an error:

> Check Out. The item <...> could not be found in your workspace, or you
>   do not have permission to access it.

File will be created, but there will be no TFS icon near it in the "Solution explorer". And the file will still be marked as deleted in the "Pending changes", not as updated.

So if I want to recreate the file, I have to

> - Remove the file
> - Check-in the changeset (which leads to broken CI-build)
> - Create the file.

**The question is:**
Is that by-design for local workspaces? Or is that just a bug, that will be fixed later? Or it's just my local bug, and nobody can reproduce it on their machines?

P.S. I need to re-create some files, for example because there are some convenient VS-tools for creating WCF RIA Domain service classes (with all related metadata), but there are no tools to update them. And I don't want to change the name of the domain service, otherwise I'll have to update clients.

**UPDATE:**
I just tried to reproduce the bug on another PC.
File Class1.cs was successfully recreated and it was marked as "updated".
There was no messagebox window, but there was the same message in the Output window:

> The item <...> could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.

If I try to recreate EDMX-model then I still get a messagebox with that error, but files are successfully recognized as edited.
I don't understand, what is the difference between these two PCs.

Comment: Could you be more clear in your question ?

Comment: OK. Can I recreate (remove-add) files using local workspace?

Comment: This is as designed. I understand you want to recreate these files as they are generated, but does that mean they have to be deleted? Couldn't you just check them out so they were writable and recreate?

Comment: Manual check-out doesn't help. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Mr.Radwan.

1. Thanks for your answer.
2. Sorry for my English.
3. I had the same settings in the Source Control options.
4. **I removed Update 1, repaired VS and reinstalled Update 1.
   Now everything works as expected.**
   When I recreate a file, now I have a message in the output window instead of the dialog window. The file is marked as edited.
5. Updating Edmx is different then recreating it from scratch. As far as I know, when you update it, EF keeps the changes you have made to the conceptual part.
   In some cases it's easier to recreate the file, then cleaning it.
6. We never stored *.generated.cs in TFS and other code that is generated automatically on each build. Anyway, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I try to reproduce your case and the answer is "Yes" and the details as the following:

The file marked as "updated". There was a message in the output window as you said but this message it makes a lot of sense because when you first delete the file, it was marked as "delete" now when you add the a file with the same name team explorer think you want to edit the file because it's still exiting on the source control so when it try to checkout for edit as it's the default configuration see the image, it can't find the file on your local worksapce because you delete it and this is the message in the output window.

[image]

The second section, you mention in your update about EDMX file:
So EDMX file updated when you use the Entity Designer to modify your model and when you use the Update Model Wizard to update your model based on changes to the underlying database, so it's generated file.

OK, let me give you a golden advice..... we don't keep any generated files in source control but we keep the files that generate them, we keep the file that we edit by hand and this the reason that we don't keep the DLLs of our code but we keep the source code that generate that DLLs.